# Why can't I associate a datatype with two floats and a string with an array with two floats and a string?

Tags: numpy

I believe the below code should work, but indeed it does not, claiming `ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'hi'` - why is it trying to convert the string to a float?

```
import numpy as np
z = {}
dt = np.dtype([('num1',np.float_),('num2',np.float_),('nm',np.unicode_,8)])
z['one'] = np.array([1.0,2.0,'hi'],dt);
z['two'] = np.array([4.0,5.0,'mom'],dt);
```

Comment: See https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html#indexing-and-assignment-to-structured-arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me if I group the elements by adding parentheses:

```
import numpy as np

z = {}
dt = np.dtype([('num1',np.float_),('num2',np.float_),('nm',np.unicode_,8)])
z['one'] = np.array([(1.0,2.0,'hi')], dt);
z['two'] = np.array([(4.0,5.0,'mom')], dt);
```

Comment: Ah, a list of a single element of a tuple ?

Comment: It looks like creating an array of tuples but it is different: e.g. `z['third'] = np.array([(1.0, 2.0, 'hi'), (4.0,)], dt);` throws an error.

Comment: Data for a structured array should be a tuple or list of tuples, with the size and type of the tuples being compatible with the dtype.